# How to approach problem with default method behaviour?

Tags: typescript

To illustrate my problem, I have simplified my code as follows:

```
class Animal {}

class Cat extends Animal {
  talk() {
    console.log('meow')
  }
}

class Tiger extends Animal {
  talk() {
    console.log('roar')
  }
}
```

So this code works like this:

```
const cat = new Cat()
cat.talk() // outputs meow
const tiger = new Tiger()
tiger.talk() // outputs roar
```

But if I do this I obviously get a problem because the method does not exist:

```
const animal = new Animal()
animal.talk() // error
```

I want all animals to have a talk method but I don't want to define one in the Animal class because I don't know the particular noise that any specific animal will make. For example, I can't say that all animals bark in the base class.

Any ideas on how to handle this? Thanks

Comment: Why not make `Animal` an interface that has a `talk()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want all animals to have a talk method but I don't want to define one in the Animal class

On Typescript 1.6 or higher, you can define the `Animal` class as an abstract class like this:

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract talk(): void;
}
```

If you do not want to define `Animal` as fully abstract, you can simply give it an abstract method:

```
class Animal {
    abstract talk(): void;
}
```

Comment: I did not know abstract classes were available in TypeScript ... Great answer, thank you dear brother :) PS love the verse on your profile

Comment: @danday74, love your profile too. Awesome to online-meet a brother in Christ here at SO.